# Rename-Sp Server and its Effects on Search Topology

Tags: 2013, search

I am planning to prepare a document for possible change after our SharePoint servers are being relocated. There are not enough information out there in web about the whole process, but I am able to get something lined up. But I still have some questions:

Here is my plan:

- remove DistributedCacheServiceinstance
- remove SharePoint server from farm
- Rename the server

  - Joint the server back to the Farm
- Add DistributedCacheserviceinstance
- reconfigure, AAM, Bindings,SSL certs.

Aside from that I had questions on Search service application. Since Search topology actively references server name, after renaming server, do we need to reconfigure search topology?

How about other service application, do we need to reconfigure them all.

Reminder Location of SQl server stays the same .

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Removing a server that contains a search topology component can affect future search activities. The extent of that effect depends on the farm search topology. We recommend that you remove or relocate any search topology components from a server before removing the server from the farm.

If you remove a server that hosts a crawl component, no index files are lost. However, you might reduce or remove the capacity to crawl content.

You can lose index files in the following situations:

- The farm has only one query component, and you remove the server that
  hosts the query component.
- You have configured the index to be partitioned and you delete the
  last query component in one of the partitions. In this case, you will
  lose a portion of the index.

[Removing a web server or application server from a SharePoint farm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263130.aspx#removewebappserver)

here is good explanation: [SP2010: Removing/Re-joining Server to a Farm Can Break Search](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/07/08/sp2010-broken-topology-and-hung-crawls-can-be-caused-by-serverid-mismatch.aspx)

Comment: On this case Would using remove-spserver be more effective then removing server from farm and rejoining it. What exactly does that cmdlet do anyway, does it change any underlying settings of the farm.